# concatanation char with char *

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function will take char then produces char* which is allocated in heap. How can I do that ?
Note : below code is not work, can you help to fix

```
Ex:

    char* foo ( char x, char * xc ) {


        xc =  realloc ( xc, 1 + strlen ( xc ) ) ;
        strcat ( xc, x ) ;

    return xc ;
    }

                             p =  heap variable
   foo ( 'a', NULL ) ==>     ------------
                             | 'a'| '\0'|
                             ------------

   foo ( 'b', p )    ===>    --------------------
                             | 'a' | 'b' | '\0' |
                             --------------------

   foo ( 'c', p )    ===>    --------------------------
                             | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | '\0' |
                             --------------------------
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `1+strlen(xc)` is only enough space for the string `xc` - there's still not enough room for lonely `char x`.

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is not a string, therefore yout must not call `strlen` on it.

```
size_t len = xc != NULL ? strlen(xc) : 0;
xc = realloc(xc, len + 1 + 1);
xc[len] = c;
xc[len + 1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

[`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) accepts two pointers. In your example you are passing a character as the second parameter

Use [`s(n)printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) family of functions instead to concatenate a character to a string.

Something like

```
len =strlen(xc);
xc =  realloc ( xc, 2 + strlen ( xc ) ) ; //One for NULL character

sprintf(xc+len,"%c", x);
```

Comment: Note that using a string as a both a destination buffer and a parameter to be formatted into the destination isn't permitted by `sprintf()` and friends.

Comment: You don't need something as heavy as `printf` family functions. You are adding ONE char at the end of a realloc'd memory. just do `int i = strlen(xc); xc[i] = c; xc[i + 1] = 0;`. Just saw Roland's answer, that's basically what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues

- In case your pointer is is NULL you would call strlen on this address.
- You're allocating not enough memory

> ```
> int len = 2;
> if ( xc != NULL ) {
>    len += strlen( xc );
> }
> xc = realloc( xc, len );
> *(xc+len-2) = x;
> *(xc+len-1) = '\0';
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
char* append_char(char c, char * str)
{
    char* new_str;

    if(NULL != str) {
        new_str = realloc(str, strlen(str) + 2);
        strncpy(new_str, str, strlen(str));
        new_str[strlen(str)] = c;
        new_str[strlen(str)+1] = '\0';
    } else {
        new_str = malloc(2);
        new_str[0] = c;
        new_str[1] = '\0';
    }

    return new_str;
}
```

Comment: No, you absolutely right. Check my edit now. Should handle that

Answer (score 0):

I can share a little sketch.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int sl = 0; // sl for strlen(s), allocated memory size will be +1 byte
char* s = NULL;

char* ccat(char* s, char c) {
    if (s == NULL) sl = 1; // allocating new memory
    else           sl = strlen(s) + 1; // +1 for new char
    // realloc will work like malloc if s is NULL
    s = realloc(s, sl+1); // +1 for zero at the end of string
    if(s == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc error");
        exit(1);
    }
    s[sl-1] = c;
    s[sl] = '\0';
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    s = ccat(s, 'Y');
    printf("sl=%d s=%s\n", sl, s);

    s = ccat(s, 'P');
    printf("sl=%d s=%s\n", sl, s);

    s = ccat(s, 'A');
    printf("sl=%d s=%s\n", sl, s);

    if (s != NULL)
        free(s);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Bad point is that it uses global variables. Good thing is that `s = ccat(NULL, 'A');` will work too. You should use a structure for several strings and their lengths if you want to deal with more strings. Also you should allocate more memory than you need right now and check if you need to reallocate it in `ccat` if you want more performance, `realloc`ing is not a cheap operation.

Comment: And please try to understand how it works and why it works so, if it is your homework task.